# SQL - Want to provide unique rank for same set of values?

Tags: sql, rank, window-functions

I need help with determining the last changed price by dates for which I am trying to generate a Unique-Identifier column, so I can apply partition to this new column and derive additional logic in my programming.
Can you please help me to derive the Unique-Identifier column?

```
Date        | OrderID   | Price | Seq_no |Unique-Indentifier  
1/24/2015   |   568956  |   300 |   1    |  1  
1/20/2015   |   568956  |   350 |   1    |  2  
1/20/2015   |   568956  |   375 |   2    |  3  
1/20/2015   |   568956  |   400 |   3    |  4  
1/17/2015   |   568956  |   400 |   1    |  4  
1/14/2015   |   568956  |   500 |   1    |  5  
1/11/2015   |   568956  |   500 |   1    |  5  
1/9/2015    |   568956  |   400 |   1    |  6  
1/7/2015    |   568956  |   400 |   1    |  6  
1/24/2015   |   568957  |   600 |   1    |  7  
1/20/2015   |   568957  |   600 |   1    |  7  
1/17/2015   |   568957  |   700 |   1    |  8  
1/14/2015   |   568957  |   800 |   1    |  9  
1/11/2015   |   568957  |   800 |   1    |  9  
1/9/2015    |   568957  |   700 |   1    |  10  
1/7/2015    |   568957  |   700 |   1    |  10
```

I can’t apply partition on Price column. Reason: For OrderID '568956' the same price 400 was set in two different dates. I wanted to isolate these two sets. If I simply use partition on Price Column then I will get all four rows as one set. So I need to put some identifier to differentiate these rows and apply partition on my new column 'UniqueIdentifier'.

```
Set 1:  
1/20/2015            568956  400         4    
1/17/2015            568956  400         4
```

```
Set 2:   
1/9/2015              568956  400         6    
1/7/2015              568956  400         6
```

If I apply partition I get the result as one set - Which I am not expecting.

```
Set 1:  
1/20/2015             568956  400         4    
1/17/2015             568956  400         4     
1/9/2015              568956  400         4    
1/7/2015              568956  400         4
```

Comment: Can you show the SQL you are using?  I don't quite understand the question and how you're getting those values for set 1

Comment: Why would you call a column "unique identifier" when it is clearly not unique?

Answer (score 0):

In your select statement do something like this:

```
SELECT
DISTINCT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Date,OrderID,Price ORDER BY Date DESC) AS RowNum
    ,Date
    ,OrderID
    ,Price
```

You may have to mess around with the `PARTITION BY` section depending on how your select statement is working but when I used this it returns a unique row number for each value.

I'm not sure if you will be able to `ORDER BY` that Date value accurately so you may have to convert it into a `DATETIME`

Answer (score 0):

You need to identify the groups, and then assign the sequential number.  One method is a difference of row numbers.  I think this is the logic:

```
select t.*,
       dense_rank() over (partition by orderid order by grp, price) as newcol
from (select t.*,
             (row_number() over partition by orderid order by date, seq_no) -
              row_number() over partition by orderid, price order by date, seq_no)
             ) as grp
      from t
     ) t
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, this really helped me. There was one problem when there are multiple price change on the same day.                          1/24/2015   |   568956  |   300 |   1    
1/20/2015   |   568956  |   350|   2                                                 1/20/2015   |   568956  |   375 |   2                                                 1/20/2015   |   568956  |   400 |   2  
1/17/2015   |   568956  |   400 |   2

Comment: @Parthi . . . Your data has no examples of that.  You need to include another column along with `date` to specify the correct ordering.

Comment: Sorry for the miss. I just updated the question.                              1/20/2015   |   568956  |   350 |   2  
1/20/2015   |   568956  |   375 |   3

Comment: You need another column besides date to define the ordering.  What is that column?

Comment: I can add a new column called seq_no

Comment: seq_no column is added.